# Auto resize of the height table not to have to scroll vertically

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if it is possible that the total height of my table is set at 100% of its parent not to have to scroll vertically and the width of the columns is automatically resized according to the content (the horizontal scroll is allowed)

Thanks in advance
(sorry for my english)

my table:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="photo">
        <th>Photo</th>  
        <td style="position:relative" class="6200000000047">
            <header>
                <button class="btn delete">Supprimer</button>
            </header>
            <img src=...></img>
        </td>
        <td style="position:relative" class="6200000000082">
            <header>
                <button class="btn delete">Supprimer</button>
            </header>
            <img src=...></img>
        </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr class="libelle">    
        <th>Libellé</th>
        <td class="6200000000047">Tablette multimédia android </td>
        <td class="6100000000082">Smartphone de demain</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="description">    
        <th>Description</th>
        <td class="6200000000047">Système dexploitation</td>
        <td class="6200000000082">Smartphone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="prix">
        <th>Prix</th>   
        <td class="6200000000047">199 €</td>
        <td class="6100000000082">999 €</td>
    </tr>                   
    <tr class="prixPerso">  
        <th>Votre prix</th> 
        <td class="6200000000047">199 €</td>
        <td class="6100000000082">999 €</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following in your css depending on the structure of your html

```
html, body
{
height: 100%;
}  body {
margin:0;
}
```